# MSI - How to Delete Files and Registry Values for a Component

Tags: windows-installer

I need to know the best way to use Windows Installer to update a previously installed component for our product where the changes include deleting some of the files and registry entries of the previous version of the component.

We're using Windows Installer directly instead of using a wrapper like Wix or InstallShield.

For each new version, we've been providing an installer .MSI file for new installs and a patch .MSP file for updates.

One of the long-existing components of the product has several DLL's and several registry entries. This component is a COM object that until now was implemented with the .NET Framework.

In the next version of our product, the set of DLL's and registry entries for this component is changed. Some DLL's are modified, some are deleted, some are added. Some registry entries are modified, some are deleted, some are added. The reason is that the COM object in this component is now implemented with .NET core instead of the older .NET Framework.

We've been creating our patch .MSP files by running msimp.exe and passing it a path to a .PCP file. The .PCP file contains the paths of the previous version .MSI file and the new version .MSI file.

We run the patch .MSP with:

msiexec /p ".msp" REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=omus

The new patch is updating and adding DLL's. But it's not deleting DLL's. Likewise, the new patch is adding and updating registry entries. But it's not deleting registry entries.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

To look at the newly created .MSP file, I open the .MSI for the previous version of the product in Orca, and then from the Orca main menu select Transform > View Patch. Orca shows the correct set of DLL's and registry entries being deleted.

Reading the docs for Windows installer, I see two possible choices for using Windows installer to delete DLL's and registry entries for an existing component when applying a patch .MSP file to update a previously installed version of a product:

1. Add entries to the RemoveFile and RemoveRegistry tables for the installer .MSI file for the new version. Build the patch .MSP by comparing the previous product version .MSI to the new product version .MSI.
2. Create a new component for the COM object DLL's and registry entries and include a row for the new component in the FeatureComponent table in the installer .MSI file for the new version of the product. Do not include a row for the previously existing component in the FeatureComponent table in the installer .MSI file for the new version of the product. Build the patch .MSP by comparing the previous product version .MSI to the new product version .MSI.

Which is the better approach?

#1 Seems wrong because we're only deleting some DLL's and Registry entries for this one new version of the product. For the next version of the product down the road, I would have to ensure that those entries in the RemoveFile and RemoveRegistry tables are not present in the new .MSI file before creating the .MSP file.

#2 Seems wrong because the new version of our product does not really have a new component, it just needs to remove some DLL's and registry entries for an existing component. Also, the windows installer docs say, "A minor upgrade can be used to add new features and components but cannot reorganize the feature-component tree". Approach #2 involves removing a component and replacing it with another one, which is reorganizing the feature-component tree. The Windows installer docs say you can't reorganize the feature-component tree without doing a major upgrade, which involves changing the product code. I don't think I should have to change the product code just to delete some DLL's and registry values for a component.

I created a Windows Installer patch .MSP file by comparing the installer .MSI file from our product's previous version with the installer .MSI file from our product's new version.

In the .MSI file for our product's new version, some DLL's and registry entries from the product's previous version have been removed.

**Expected:**
A Windows Installer patch .MSP file created by comparing the installer .MSI files from the product's previous version and new version deletes DLL's and registry entries that are no longer present in a previously existing component.

**Actual:**
DLL's and registry entries that are no longer present in an existing component are not getting deleted when the patch .MSP file is applied.